# How to filter this songs by amount tracks in an Album

Tags: java, lambda, stream

I have the next Class.

```java
public class Track{
    private int id;
    private String trackName;
    private String artistName;
    private String albumName;
    private int amountMembers;
    private int duration; //segs
    private String category;
    private int albumYear;
    private boolean isSolist; //1 yes, 0 no 
}
```

I have a lot of `Track` in a List and I want to filter the Tracks by two requirements:

- If category equals "rock"
- If the track belongs to an album with less than 9 tracks

The first it's easy, I currently have the Tracks in a List filtered by the category "rock" but I can't imagine how can I do a function that filter and return the Tracks that are in an album with less than 9 songs. Any Solution? I'm using Java, I can use Streams or Lambdas?. IMPORTANT: I have a flat list of tracks in my DB.

Comment: Hint: your requirements mention *Tracks* and **Albums**. So the question is: how does the data model for Albums look like? Or do you just have a *flat* list of all the Tracks in your "database"? In other words: maybe you should step back and rework your *model*, and base it on albums? Just as example. Anyway, we probably cant help you, because as said: we dont know all the relevant aspects. Please share them with us!

Comment: Hi!, I have a flat list of all the tracks as you mentioned.

Comment: Then I strongly recommend that you at least introduce an Album class. Because you really want to be able to say `this.album.equals(that.album)` when you need to order/compare things. Because otherwise, you get into the business of comparing multiple fields (like album name, year, etc) ... if you want to be real. Sure, that depends how realistic you want to go. But figuring: there might be 2, 3 versions of the "same" album from the same year isn't too unrealistic.

Comment: I will try, thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You could use lambda with your logic

```java
Predicate<Track> isTrackRock = t -> "rock".equals(t.getCategory());

Predicate<Track> hasAlbumLessThan9Traks = t -> t... // get all album with count of tracks

var listOftrack = new ArrayList<Track>();


var newList  =  listOftrack
                    .stream()
                    .filter(isTrackRock)
                    .filter(hasAlbumLessThan9Traks)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I suggest you get already filtered from db for better performance

Comment: Mm thanks, how can I filter that? I'm using MySQL

Comment: What are you using for getting data from database? hibernate, jdbdTemplate, Spring-data with repositoriy, customizing manually select and connect on pure java?

Comment: Hibernate and Using CrudRepository for get the content from the tables

Comment: This will help you to declare your method on CrudRepository `CrudRepository` with `@Query` https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query

Comment: Thanks, I will read it!

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested properly but you could try this :

```
    listOfTracks.stream()
            .filter(track -> "rock".equals(track.getCategory()))
            .filter(track -> listOfTracks.stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Track::getAlbumName, Collectors.counting())).get(track.getAlbumName()) < 9L)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If it works and it is what you need, you can try to also add a variable for listOfTracks.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Track::getCategory, Collectors.counting()))